# Material Design Lite badge change color

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm using Material Design Lite (getmdl.io) for my web app, I have a card that has a badge with number of notifications.

I tried this css code but without change:

```
.mdl-badge {
  background: #FF3D00;
}
```

I can't change the color of the badge is this a problem in the framework?

Comment: Can you include the HTML for this card with notification badge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Material badge is actually applied as an [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) CSS [psuedo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

You can write a CSS selector to change the background color of the badge as follows,

```
.mdl-badge[data-badge]:after {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

---

*Notice there is also an attribute selector used; learn more about those here:*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors*

Comment: thanks it's work ... i think i should learn more about css selectors

Comment: Hopefully the resources I linked will help you out!